# Camera going dark after starting recording

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I have an activity where i am using front camera to record video .
Everything is working fine , the only problem is that camera preview goes pretty dark when i start recording video .

Before pressing start button(to record video) -

[Screenshot 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y42qy6osryq093s/Screenshot_20160814-010315%5B2%5D.png?dl=0)

and after pressing start button -

[ScreenShot 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1husa49xmtj5iyz/Screenshot_20160814-010321%5B1%5D.png?dl=0)

I have not posted code here because i just want to understand first what can be the reason behind this . Is this because of any camera properties that i dont know of ? .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: @HaDenG nope....please let me know if you found one.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you probably changed your phone by now but i have the same problem with my ASUS Zenfone 3 MAX, it didn't happen at first but after several updates, this behavior is constant through all apps.

So, i installed OPEN CAMERA and started messing with the settings, and i noticed that when i set the FPS from the default 30 to force 60 the issue goes away and video records perfectly (IN OPEN CAMERA), but not on the rest of the apps (like using Whatsapp or Messenger buil-in video recording capabilities).

My guess is this has something to do with some update screwing up the Shutter speed of some cameras and it just doesn't let enough light go in at 30fps. Why? no idea. But this worked for me and maybe you can find a more... technical solution through code? dunno, good luck!

Comment: Oh, just a note, even if i use OPEN CAMERA, but at 30 FPS, the issue still occurs, but at 60fps or more, everything is fine and the video is crystal clear, so i'm pretty sure it's not about the camera app, but the FPS and shutter speed (which most apps use 30 by default).